# Nodejs Promise TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I got error when i try to access function of `controller` in my `route`. I used mongoose,express.

error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at /private/var/www/html/sms/server/routes/user.routes.js:70:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
>       at router (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/private/var/www/html/sms/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at /private/var/www/html/sms/server.js:65:3 POST /api/user/create 500 27.274 ms - 16 (node:11300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: This email is
>   already exists. Please enter another email. (node:11300) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

here is my code:-

**user.cont.js**

```
function create(data) {
  User.findOne({ email: data.email })
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return reject(err);
        })
      } else {
        if (doc) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return reject(new Error('This email is already exists. Please enter another email.'));
          })
        } else {
          const user = new User(data);
          return user.save()
        }
      }

    })

}


export default { getUsers, create };
```

**user.route.js**

```
router.post('/create', (req, res, next) => {
        UserCtrl.create(req.body)
            .then(savedUser => res.json(savedUser)) . // here error is generated
            .catch(e => next(e));
    });
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` in your `create` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the whole `User.findOne()` call in a Promise, like so:

```
function create(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.findOne({ email: data.email })
      .exec((err, doc) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        if (doc) return reject(new Error('This email is already exists. Please enter another email.'))
        const user = new User(data)
        user.save((err) => {
          if (err) return reject(err)
          resolve()
        })
      })
  })
}
```

You also need to resolve the promise, otherwise the callbacks in your `UserCtrl.then()` calls will never be called. I also added error handling in case something goes wrong with saving a new `User` to the database.

Comment: of course, in current versions of Mongoose, `.findOne` returns a Promise, so you can avoid this promise constructor anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your controller and route code to be like like this as well.

**user.cont.js**

```js
function create(req, res, next){
   User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then((err, user) => {

      if(user){

        const newUser = User.create(req.body,  (newUser, err) => {
          if(err) res.send(err);

          delete newUser.password;
          res.json(newUser)
        })
      }


    }).catch((err) => {
       res.send(err)
    })


}
```

Since `User.findOne` already returns a promise you can call `.then` on it, also make sure you delete the user's password if they have one before you return it to the client for security reasons!

Note you can also call a `.then` on the create function, maybe you could refactor that to use `.then` for practice :)

---

**user.route.js**

`router.post('/create', UserCtrl.create)`

Now your routes code looks a lot cleaner and you are following separation of concerns much better!